# 61.129 (a)(3)(v), can it be with multiple instructors?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

My question is can the 3 hours in prep for the check ride be done with different instructors, or does it have to be all 3 hours with the same instructor? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're referring to US FAA regulations, so I added the appropriate tag. If my guess is wrong, then please [Edit] to indicate the jurisdiction in question.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you.

Comment: There are lots of regulations that are ambiguous. This isn’t one of them. If they wanted it to be with only one instructor they would have said so. It is common to have multiple instructors for the checkride prep. Often a primary instructor will have another instructor give a mock checkride to the student so that the student gets practice performing under pressure with someone they aren’t used to flying with.

Comment: Thank you. This helps greatly.

Comment: Nothing in the regs say that you have to do anything with one instructor. But nothing in the regs says you can force an instructor to sign off on something he/she does not want to sign. Ask before you hire an instructor.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no requirement per se that multiple instructors cannot do this.  However, the CFI giving you the logbook endorsement to take the practical will probably want to log that time with you for liability reasons.